# how to add a variable in another variable?

Tags: php

this must be simple for most, how to add a variable in another variable?

this variable `$objResult["price"]` has a value of `5`:

```
echo $objResult["price"]; //it shows `5`
```

I want to make something like:

```
$newVariable = $objResult["price"];
echo $newVariable; //nothing happens
```

This is not working for me. `echo $newVariable;` it's not showing anything.

but this way it does not work.

I tried:

```
$newVariable = echo $objResult["price"];
$newVariable = print $objResult["price"];
$newVariable = echo ${$objResult["price"]};
```

but without luck! Can anyone help?

---

For abstract:

If I do:

```
echo $objResult["price"];
```

It shows **5**

If i do:

```
$newVariable = $objResult["price"];
echo $newVariable;
```

nothing happens.

Comment: This is a terrible question. First of all, you say `$newVariable = $objResult["price"];` doesn't work, but you're wrong. If you mean you want to get a variable named `$5` out of this... you want variable variables and you should use `${$objResult['price']} = 'your value'` like in your last example, but without the echo and the other way around.

Comment: @scrowler Except $5 is not a valid PHP variable :)

Comment: @Jessica, correct - however there's always a workaround: https://eval.in/81263

Comment: It sounds like $objResult is not even set

Comment: $objResult["price"]; is from DataBase... i need to make some math with those data, that comes from DB, and i decided to make simple VARIABLE from them, but it looks it doesn't work!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very close!

```
$newVariable = $objResult["price"];
echo $newVariable;
```

Comment: this is not working for me: if i make echo $objResult["price"]; it shows 5, but if i make in the way you submited, its not showing anything

Comment: @AndrewS then you're doing something wrong. That's extremely basic PHP syntax there...

Comment: I know it looks strange, but it is really a stupid problem... I tried same think about 20 times, and it doesnt work!!! I knwo this way should work, i tried it first time, but its not working.

Comment: and if i make $varibale = $objResult["price"];

Comment: echo $variable, nothing happens

Comment: Copy and paste your actual code into the question, because your comments have multiple spelling errors.

Answer (score 0):

Your first attempt (given below) is correct for assigning the value to another variable.

```
$newVariable = $objResult["price"];
```

Now, if you want to print this value, you can do:

```
echo $newVariable;
```

Otherwise, if you are experiencing some other issue, please update your question :)

Answer (score -1):

You said that this didn't work:

```
$newVariable = $objResult["price"];
echo $newVariable;
```

Yet that's you accepted answer. If somebody else comes here with a similar problem I'll show how the above may not work. **I'm not saying this is the case of the OP**, *I don't freaking know what is the case of the OP.*

---

If the value of `$objResult["price"]` is is not an string then when you call `echo` on it it may be calling `__toString()` on it. This is documented beviour described at [Magic Methods at php.net](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php#object.tostring).

So, when you call `echo` on an object it will convert it to string automatically.

In this case the code:

```
echo $objResult["price"];
```

Is equivalent to

```
echo $objResult["price"].__toString();
```

On the other hand when you have the code:

```
$newVariable = $objResult["price"];
echo $newVariable;
```

It will be equivalent to this:

```
$newVariable = $objResult["price"];
echo $newVariable.__toString();
```

If the first works and the second don't, then it means that you have an odd implementation of `__toString()`. You could mitigate the problem by doing the following:

```
$newVariable = $objResult["price"].__toString();
echo $newVariable;
```